# What tool can constantly remind user to complete a task, until it is finished?

Tags: linux, reminders

I want to maintain a study routine, where I study everyday for 1 hour. Some days I forget to do this, so would like to find some software that helps me not to forget.

- Preferably, this frequently gives me an on-screen alert of some form, until I click "completed". This might be a highly visible status bar icon, libnotify-type notification, or pop-up dialog window.
- I do not need a complicated calendar tool.

Is there any software that can constantly remind users to complete a task, which goes quiet until the next day, when the same task is due again?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be a cron job calling something like `notify-send 'Do your homework!'`. Try in in a terminal to see if it might fit your needs.

If you're running Ubuntu, you could install `Scheduled Tasks` and have a nice GUI and avoind messing with cron. Have your notification pop up every hour on the hour, once a day, whatever you want.

The downside . . . no simple way to dismiss it, and it doesn't stay up, but it's really simple.